# No route matches [POST] "/author/test_author/24/steps_author/13"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, simple-form

I have a form that will work sometimes and sometimes not and I can't work out what is changing between times, other than restarting the rails app. Currently it isn't working.

I have these entries in my routes file:

```
constraints :subdomain => 'my' do
  namespace 'my', path: nil do
    namespace 'author' do
      resources :test_author do
        resources :steps_author
        [...]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The particular routes I'm interested in here produce this from `rake routes`

```
my_author_test_author_steps_author GET        /author/test_author/:test_author_id/steps_author/:id(.:format)   my/author/steps_author#show {:subdomain=>"my"}
                                   PUT        /author/test_author/:test_author_id/steps_author/:id(.:format)   my/author/steps_author#update {:subdomain=>"my"}
                                   DELETE     /author/test_author/:test_author_id/steps_author/:id(.:format)   my/author/steps_author#destroy {:subdomain=>"my"}
```

My form opening looks like this (using simple form and bootstrap):

```
<%= simple_form_for @step, :url => my_author_test_author_steps_author_path(@step), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening?

#### Update

Based on the help from juanpastas it seems that the form is rendering correctly however Rails is interpreting the request as a POST and not a PUT. Though for the life of me I can't work out why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass complete params in route

```
<%= simple_form_for @step, 
  :url => my_author_test_author_steps_author_path(author, @step),
  :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

After reading your title I see you should be making POST to `/author/test_author/24/steps_author/` without the last number. What about:

```
<% url = !@step.persisted? ? '/author/test_author/24/steps_author/' : my_author_test_author_steps_author_path(author, @step) %>
<%= simple_form_for @step,
  :url => url,
  :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

I have harcoded route because I am not sure about your route helper name. You can run `rake routes` to find that helper.

Comment: Yeah I had tried a few variations like that and including your example but couldn't get it to work. What you have gives an error. If I have `(:author, @step)` then the form renders but submitting it still gives the routing error.

Comment: where does the form is submitting? I mean what does `action` and `method` attributes in form says? do action and method appear in rake routes?

Comment: I suppose if `@step` is not persisted you will be making a POST, which I don't see in `rake routes`.

Comment: The form has `action="/author/test_author/46/steps_author/40"` and `method="post"` but the form also has the hidden input field `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />`. So everything looks to be in order.

Comment: Is your server failing with PUT to `/author/test_author/46/steps_author/40`?

Comment: Pretty much. But only on one particular case. All the other instances of calling the update route on this controller seem to be fine. There is a nested polymorphic association which can modify the form based on the nested type. All the types work except this one. Though it has worked in the past.